# ActionScript 3.0 get BoundingBox of MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I get the BoundingBox of a MovieClip? if the contents of the movieclip have they're lowest coordinate at the movieclips origin then it's easy (just take width and height of the movieclip and add them to the coordinates of the mc). but how to do it for an arbitrary movieclip?

Comment: globalToLocal and localToGlobal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the ActionScript reference for `getBounds()` or `getRect()`.